Words for an association of an object with an emotion
How would you coin a word, for:

a word, for dealing with a person, where

...

the word was something in a situational experience

the situation, was known to the listener

the situation, was associated with a feeling or an emotion (or, a blur, between the two

the object was presented to the listener to recall the emotion

(and, perhaps, the emotion resulted from an implicit, conversation, which, may (or may not, have nothing to do with the situation


The word, described something the person applied or did
Thanks.

Overall, that was not a positive experience. Perhaps, I should delete my post.
